# How do I check if a tab exists in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Currently I use this to check if a tab(element) already exists:

```
if(!$('#'+element).length){
   //... code to add new tab if not exists.
} else {
   Alert("Tab or portlet already exists...");
}
```

This is very dirty and I get a "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #" from FireBug. If element already exists, the "Alert" doesn't show, I think it hangs at the first exception.

Is there a better way to check if an element exists? (Or a tab)

I am using this for my personal project @ http://www.soliman.nl/test/jqueryui/ui_2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your source - you are passing "#foo" as the parameter element, then prepending another "#".  The result is `$("##foo")`, which just isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

please check value of **element**

coz if this is null or empty your statement become

```
if(!$('#').length){
or
if(!$('#null').length){
```

which may through some error

here is working version

```
​<html>
<body>
    <p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
var element = "test"; //if you try to comment this line or change value , it will give error 
if(!$('#'+element).length){
   alert("do something");

} else {
   alert("Tab or portlet already exists...");
}​
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/J3MdK/

Comment: You need to comment your comment in the `var element` line.